# ping receives no packets, but tcpdump can see them coming in

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, centos, openvz

I'm migrating an old Ubuntu OpenVZ instance (Jaunty) to a new CentOS 6.3 host (using vzdump/vzrestore).

Now networking does not work properly. Facts:

- It works just fine if a setup a new OpenVZ instance.
- I can connect INTO the old instance perfectly well, but it cannot connect to the outside.
- It cannot ping the host, nor anything else.
- I've cleared all iptables rules both on host and inside the VE.

ping:

```
root@dolores:/# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
11 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9999ms
```

At the same time within the VE:

```
17:49:12.730360 IP dolores > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 59701, seq 1, length 64
17:49:12.735095 IP 8.8.8.8 > dolores: ICMP echo reply, id 59701, seq 1, length 64
17:49:13.730305 IP dolores > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 59701, seq 2, length 64
17:49:13.735524 IP 8.8.8.8 > dolores: ICMP echo reply, id 59701, seq 2, length 64
17:49:14.730411 IP dolores > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 59701, seq 3, length 64
```

This output occasionally occurs with some delay, I believe because tcpdump tries to reverse-DNS the ips involved:

```
17:47:20.977819 IP dolores.40623 > 213.133.98.97.domain: 60247+ PTR? 8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa. (38)
```

I can run tcpdump on the host and get the same output immediately.

Of course, `/sys/devices/virtual/net/venet0/statistics/rx_bytes` is updating, and none of the `/sys/devices/virtual/net/venet0/statistics/rx_` error files make a peep.

What's the deal? Where would I look now? The problem must be related to the Ubuntu VE itself, I assume, since it works with newly created ones.

Some more output in case it helps:

```
root@dolores:/# ifconfig -a
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:127.0.0.2  P-t-P:127.0.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:39652 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:39398 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3344760 (3.3 MB)  TX bytes:3303115 (3.3 MB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:78.46.236.xxx  P-t-P:78.46.236.xxx  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

.

```
root@dolores:/# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         *               0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 venet0
```

On the host:

```
[root@olive ~]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
static.xxx.236. *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 venet0
78.46.236.xxx   *               255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
default         gw-wan2.little- 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: please post also the output of `ipchains -v -L INPUT`

Comment: ``iptables -t nat -L && iptables -t filter -L && iptables -t mangle -L`` is completely empty on both host and VE.

Comment: ups, sorry, I missed that you cleared out iptables.

Comment: @miracle2k What is the default policy for the INPUT chain?

Comment: Everything is set to ALLOW. It's nothing obvious like that. Keep in mind that it works for newly created VEs.

Comment: `ifconfig` and `route` are deprecated on linux. Please use `ip addr` and `ip route` instead.

Comment: I know it's too late but were you able to figure out a problem? I'm facing a similar problem with kvm with linux bridges setup.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same symptoms but not with a virtual machine. I've fixed it up.
There was a problem with my SNAT setup and `ip rule` which didn't match.

Run `ip route`, should have one line...

```
default dev venet0  scope link
```

Run `ip rule`, should have 3 lines...

```
0:  from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```